# "On the Road" is broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2014

I asked a question about an hour ago via my iPhone and the official SE app, though *On The Road* hasn't been awarded yet.

Is it broken?

Comment: It appears *Selfie* is broken as well.

Comment: Yep. Those haven't achieved their "Implicit quality requirements".

Comment: @JonEricson Got it, thanks :)